# Why does use Simplify Sqrt/Abs and not just Abs in Vector Normalization?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
Simplify[Normalize[{Sin[a] Sin[c], Cos[c] Sin[a], 0}], Element[{a, c}, Reals]]
```

gives me

```
{(Sin[a] Sin[c])/Sqrt[Abs[Cos[c] Sin[a]]^2 + Abs[Sin[a] Sin[c]]^2], (
 Cos[c] Sin[a])/Sqrt[Abs[Cos[c] Sin[a]]^2 + Abs[Sin[a] Sin[c]]^2], 0}
```

and not

```
{(Sin[a] Sin[c])/Abs[Sin[a]], (Cos[c] Sin[a])/Abs[Sin[a]], 0}
```

if i simplify the divider without sqrt

```
Simplify[Cos[c]^2 Sin[a]^2 + Sin[a]^2 Sin[c]^2, Element[{a, c}, Reals]]
```

gives me

```
Sin[a]^2
```

and then use

```
Simplify[{(Sin[a] Sin[c])/Sqrt[Sin[a]^2], (Cos[c] Sin[a])/Sqrt[Sin[a]^2], 0}, Element[{a, c}, Reals]]
```

i get the result

```
{(Sin[a] Sin[c])/Abs[Sin[a]], (Cos[c] Sin[a])/Abs[Sin[a]], 0}
```

is there anything is miss or could i help Mathematica to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) doesn't go far enough, use [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
FullSimplify[Normalize[{Sin[a] Sin[c], Cos[c] Sin[a], 0}], 
 Element[{a, c}, Reals]]

(*  {Sign[Sin[a]] Sin[c], Cos[c] Sign[Sin[a]], 0}  *)
```

The `Sign[Sin[a]]` is simpler and equivalent to `Sin[a]/Abs[Sin[a]]` provided `a != 0`

```
FullSimplify[Sign[Sin[a]] == Sin[a]/Abs[Sin[a]], Element[a, Reals] && a != 0]

(*  True  *)

LeafCount /@ {Sign[Sin[a]], Sin[a]/Abs[Sin[a]]}

(*  {3, 8}  *)
```

Comment: Thx for your help - even better result